# Detect asterisk (shift + 8) in javascript case statement

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of code that is supposed to detect when an asterisk in pressed. This is for a ***barcode scanner***. However, obviously this is detecting whenever an 8 is pressed. How do I detect when ***Shift+8 is pressed***? I have tried a number of methods. I can detect when the shift is done using `var isShift = !!e.shiftKey`; but when I tried an if statement it still does not work. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
 (function( $ ) {
$.fn.mmpBarcodeReader = function() {
    // Initialize buffer, it will contain the barcode scanner output

    $(this).data('mmpBarcodeBuffer', '');
    // Listen to barcode scanner output
    $(this).keydown(function(e){
        //console.log(this);
        //console.log(e);
        switch (e.which) {
            // STX Prefix (Start of Text)
            case 56:
                if(e.shiftKey) {
                    $(this).trigger('start.mmp.barcodereader');
                    $(this).data('mmpBarcodeReading', true);
                    break;
                  } else {
                    console.log('without shift');
                  }   

            // ETX Suffix (End of Text)
            case 13:
                $(this).trigger('end.mmp.barcodereader', $(this).data('mmpBarcodeBuffer'));
                $(this).data('mmpBarcodeReading', false);
                $(this).data('mmpBarcodeBuffer', '');
                break;
            // Regular char
            default:
                if ($(this).data('mmpBarcodeReading')){
                    $(this).trigger('char.mmp.barcodereader', String.fromCharCode(e.which));
                    $(this).data('mmpBarcodeBuffer', $(this).data('mmpBarcodeBuffer') + String.fromCharCode(e.which));
                }
                break;
        }
    });
    // Sometimes the STX Prefix triggers alternately the keyup & keydown events. Let's fix it!
    $(this).keyup(function(e){
        if (e.which == 20){
            $(this).trigger('start.mmp.barcodereader');
            $(this).data('mmpBarcodeReading', true);
        }
    });
};
```

}( jQuery ));

UPDATE:
Thank you both for getting back to me. It appears as though this issue was not as straightforward as I thought, therefore I will provide much more information. So this script is for scanning barcodes. The barcodes are prefixed by an asterisk to signal the beginning. The problem is it was seeing just the number 8 as the beginning. I finally did what I should have just done from the beginning and change the prefix on the scanner itself to a grave accent.

It is now working perfectly. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead of [`KeyboardEvent.which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) (btw - removed from the standards). The `KeyboardEvent.key` property returns a printable character if it can, or the name of the for controls, white space (such as Enter), and special keys (for other cases read the documentation at the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)).

So in your case it will return an *** (asterisk)** for *shift + 8*, and **Enter** for the *Enter* key.

```js
demo.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  switch(e.key) {
    case '*':
      console.log('asterisk');
      break;
      
    case 'Enter':
      console.log('Enter');
      break;
      
    default:
      console.log('something else');
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="demo">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why you would be getting an error using an `if` statement in a `switch`, but here is an example of how to use it.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 56:
      if (e.shiftKey) {
        console.log('asterisk');
      } else {
        console.log('8');
      }
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<input>
```

Just make sure the `if` is inside of the `case` and that you still have a `break` if necessary.

Doing `!!e.shiftKey` for an implicit boolean conversion shouldn't hurt anything, but it's also redundant and unnecessary.